# Application not getting installed and returning null on Android for the below code

Tags: android, multithreading

Hi I'm a newbie to Android please help me out, I'm trying to set time for my Splash screen with the below code but the application doesn't get installed and returns NULL. I'm using Android 4.1.2

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    //how long until we go to the next activity
    protected boolean _active = true;
    protected int _splashTime = 5000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);         

        // thread for displaying the SplashScreen
        Thread splashTread = new Thread() {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int waited = 0;
                        while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                            sleep(100);
                            if(_active) {
                                waited += 100;
                            }
                        }
                    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing
                    } finally {

                        stop();
                    }
                }
            };
            splashTread.start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This question is confusing. What null, and what do you mean when you say "not installed"? Secondly, you're using a forced five second splash screen? Good luck on your user reviews.

Comment: I want the screen to stay active for some time and then get deactive.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to display your splash screen even before the activity is visible.
NOTE: The activity is visible only after onCreate() is finished.